# How do I stop Rhythmbox from launching when I try opening a folder on my desktop?

Tags: rhythmbox

This has been bugging me since I updated from Mint to Ubuntu recently:
Any time I click on a directory link outside of the file browser (desktop, removable media shown in dock, removable media notification, etc) Rhythmbox launches instead of the file browser. Every. Time.

There has to be a way to stop that from happening, it drives me crazy.

Started after updating from Mint (previous LTS) to Ubuntu 19.10 and now still in Ubuntu 20.04

--edit--
Adding xdg-mime info as requested:

```
$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
rhythmbox-device.desktop
```

Kinda shows the issue; how do I fix that?

Comment: can you show `xdg-mime query default inode/directory`  please.

Comment: Added output @nobody

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @nobody for pointing me in the right direction. After his(?) question I figured I might as well try:

```
$ xdg-mime default Files.desktop inode/directory
```

and it worked. I can just click on all the things now without Rhythmbox hijacking.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you so much for posting that sollution! I was tinkiering and trying to solve that for hours.. For those of you who preffere Nemo instead defult files menager try bellow:

```
 xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory
```

Works on Ubuntu 22.04!!